# where to find implementation source code of methods

Tags: java, c#

For example I am trying to find the implementation source code of the method startsWith

How can I find the source code for java and c#?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

thanks

Comment: I can't speak for the c#, but for Java, you can either look up the source of OpenJDK (not guaranteed to be the same as Oracle's Java), or decompile the class files.

Answer (score 2):

For c# you can check reference source.

[string class in reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2596)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

> 1. Go to [grepCode](http://grepcode.com/) and search.
> 2. Go to your java installation like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\src.zip.

extract the zip and link it to your IDE

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link for java source code

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.startsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? notpad?
A decent IDE will support going to the source by pressing a hot key.

For example in Eclipse:

```
String abc ="abc";
abc.startsWith("a");
```

Click on startsWith then hit F3 and Eclipse pulls this up:

```
public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
    return startsWith(prefix, 0);
}
```

Again click on startsWith on the line with the return and hit F3:

```
public boolean startsWith(String prefix, int toffset) {
    char ta[] = value;
    int to = toffset;
    char pa[] = prefix.value;
    int po = 0;
    int pc = prefix.value.length;
    // Note: toffset might be near -1>>>1.
    if ((toffset < 0) || (toffset > value.length - pc)) {
        return false;
    }
    while (--pc >= 0) {
        if (ta[to++] != pa[po++]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (dating back for as long as I can remember) you can right click the method name and select "Go to definition".

If the method is in a .NET assembly for which you do not have the source code for, you can try [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).